# SDL Draw Rect after Line Pixel issue

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

When I draw in SDL a rectangle after a line I got a pixel colored like the Line, on top of the right top corner of the rectangle. It doesn't matter if the line and the rectangle have a different color. There is always a pixel on the right top corner of the rectangle when I draw the rectangle after the line.

Here is my code for the rectangle:

```
SDL_Rect srcrect;

srcrect.x = 50;
srcrect.y = 50;
srcrect.w = 150;
srcrect.h = 80;
```

Here is my code were I drawing it:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 20, 20, 300, 300);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &srcrect);
    
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Here is a picture of the whole render:

[image: Full Render]

Here is a picture zoomed in on the top right corner of the rectangle:

[image: Top Right Corner]

When I draw draw the rectangle before the line I don't have this issue.
Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

**Edit:**

When I draw a second rectangle there is no pixel issue on this rectangle. It's only on the first rectangle after the line.

**Edit 2:**

I found a post about the exact same problem. There is also just the solution with the `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer()`. Here is the link:
[What could be causing stray pixels to appear in my SDL2 program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826191/what-could-be-causing-stray-pixels-to-appear-in-my-sdl2-program)

Comment: Can you repro with `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer()`?

Comment: With the SoftwareRenderer it works, but is there a way to fix this with the normal `SDL_CreateRenderer()`?

Comment: You [got](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/4001) a [selection](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/2006) of [bugs](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/1700) to [direct](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/1626) your time/money at :)

Comment: I looked at the bugs but it didn't helped me for my problem.

Comment: Did you try throwing your program through RenderDoc to see the individual 3D API (D3D? OpenGL? Whatever!) calls and their results on your frame buffers (ie, screen)? It will at least point to why it's happening, if not how to solve it.

Comment: When I start the application in RenderDoc on my program Window it shows: ```OpenGL. Context not created via CreateContextAttribs. Capturion disabled. Only OpenGL 3.2+ contexts are supportet.``` In the Log Tab its shows some errors, some gl functions (glMatrixMode, glLoadIdentify, glColor4f, glOrtho, glBegin, glVertex2f, glEnd) not supported - capture may be broken. I used RenderDoc for the first time, maybe it could show more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the problem could be, maybe your renderer flags? Window flags? Have you set the blend mode? Ie, `SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);` Maybe that will change something? Personally for me it didn't when I made this tiny program, it didn't change anything.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 0, 30, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;


    SDL_Rect srcrect = {50,50,150,80};


    while (running)
    {

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }



        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);



        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 20, 20, 300, 300);

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &srcrect);



        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    }


    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();


    return 0;
}
```

Maybe give this program a run and see if it has the same problem.

Comment: With your example I got the exact same problem.

Comment: maybe a driver issue, its not appearing for me, possibly an SDL2 version issue aswell? I'd update my drivers and get the latest SDL2 version and if not might be one of those artefact gpu issues, I can't see how its a software side issue if that code isn't working.